# How can I install packages from unusual repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, vsftpd

I want vsftpd_3.0.3-3ubuntu2

It is a bit old but I can't upgrade any further, being on a 32 bits machine.

This package is still available in many places. For example:

https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vsftpd/
Index of /ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/v/vsftpd

I guess I should write something in /etc/apt/sources.list
but what?

I tried the obvious:
deb http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/ubuntu/ main

But it said:
Malformed entry 61 in list file ...
The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: I'm stupid stupid stupid. I carefully configured the iptables to only leave the ports 20, 21, 22 80 and 443 opened. I thought this was what was needed for, respectively, ftp-data, ftp, ssh, http and https. So I blocked everything else. Then I couldn't use apt and I wondered what was wrong... I deleted all the iptables rules and now I have my vsftpd. I'll leave the question opened, though, it might be useful. Poor computer.

Comment: Do you have an answer?  If so, post the solution below. Give us step-by-step instructions how to fix the problem. That will make this Q&A useful to future visitors.